# Can't get active navigation to work based on URL / jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a simple menu, but I can't seem to get the active navigation to work. I think it may have something to do with the code being based on the URL being /about whereas I use the full URL in my links (ie. http://helloarchie.blue/about)?

HTML:

```
<ul id="naviga">
    <li><a href="http://helloarchie.blue/">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="http://helloarchie.blue/category/motherhood/">Motherhood</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="http://helloarchie.blue/category/fashion-friday/">Fashion</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="http://helloarchie.blue/category/reviews/">Reviews</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="http://helloarchie.blue/category/blogging-tips/">Blogging</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="http://helloarchie.blue/category/lifestyle/">Lifestyle</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="http://helloarchie.blue/about/">About</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="http://helloarchie.blue/contact-me/">Contact</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
#naviga li {
    display: inline;
    padding: 0 2%;
    text-align: center;
    font-family:"brandon-grotesque", "HelveticaNeue", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    font-size: 0.75em;
}
#naviga li a {
    position: relative;
}
#naviga li a:hover {
    color: #585858;
    font-weight: bold;
}
#naviga li a::before {
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    background: #f6a889;
    height: 2px;
    margin-top: -17px;
    margin-left: -2px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 0%;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.65s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.65s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.65s ease;
    transition: all 0.65s ease;
}
#naviga li a:hover::before {
    width: 100%;
}
#naviga li a .active {
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    background: #f6a889;
    height: 2px;
    margin-top: -16px;
    margin-left: -2px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

JS:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     url = window.location.pathname;
     url = url.substring(1);
     if (url == '') {
         url = 'home';
     }
     $('#naviga li.active').removeClass('active');
     $('#naviga li').each(function () {
         if ($(this).hasClass(url)) {
             $(this).addClass('active');
         }
     });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there, just a couple of minor issues:

1. Your JS seems to imply that you want to style the `<li>` with the `active` CSS class. However, your CSS implies that you want to style the `<a>` within the `<li>`.
2. You are matching the URL against a classname that an `<li>` element might have. However, in your HTML, none of the `<li>` elements have a class assigned to them.

In short: give each `<li>` the appropriate classname (e.g., 'home') and update your CSS so that the `<li>` gets styled (or update the JS accordingly).